# How to fetch RTC work item change sets using plain java api?

Tags: java, rtc, workitem

I am trying to fetch the changes using below code but every time it returns null. I don't know what is wrong with this code.

```
ILinkManager fLinkManager = (ILinkManager) repo.getClientLibrary(ILinkManager.class);
        IReferenceFactory fReferenceFactory = fLinkManager.referenceFactory();
        IReference reference = fReferenceFactory.createReferenceToItem(workItem.getItemHandle());

        ILinkQueryPage page = fLinkManager.findLinksByTarget("com.ibm.team.filesystem.workitems.change_set", reference,
                monitor);
        ILinkCollection linkCollection = page.getAllLinksFromHereOn();
        Collection<ILink> links = linkCollection.getLinksById("com.ibm.team.filesystem.workitems.change_set");
```

Comment: What exact line returns null?

Comment: even if there are some change sets but the size of links collection is zero.

Comment: @VonC any suggestion?

Comment: Would https://jazz.net/forum/questions/3385/getting-related-artifacts-for-iworkitems work better? Or https://jazz.net/forum/questions/3392/fetching-change-set-for-work-item/3394?

Comment: @VonC Can you please check this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506594/how-to-fetch-complete-change-set-linked-to-the-work-item

Comment: I have found the links where I can get the information about change sets but there is some exception I have explained in above link.

Comment: @VonC need you help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549128/how-to-fetch-change-set-by-work-item-link-targetref-uri

Comment: @VonC can you please help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768795/how-to-find-out-if-work-item-change-set-file-item-is-newly-added-or-modified