# How to fetch complete change set linked to the work item?

Tags: java, api, rtc

I am using below code to resolve and fetch the change set data

```
IChangeSet changeSet = null;
        try{
            for(Object wI : links1){
                ILink link = (ILink) wI;
                Object source = link.getTargetRef().resolve();
                IItemHandle changeSetHandle = (IItemHandle) link.getTargetRef().resolve();
                if (source instanceof IChangeSetHandle) {
                    changeSet = (IChangeSet) repo.itemManager().fetchCompleteItem(changeSetHandle,
                            IItemManager.DEFAULT, monitor);
                    System.out.println("changeset---1"+changeSet);
                }
            }
            return parentWorkItemIds;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Using above code I am getting below exception :

```
com.ibm.team.repository.common.ItemNotFoundException: CRJAZ0215E The following record was not found in the database: com.ibm.team.scm.common.internal.impl.ChangeSetHandleImpl
```