# How to fetch change set by work item link targetRef URI?

Tags: java, api, rtc

First please let me know the difference between these two

1. com.ibm.team.filesystem.workitems.change_set
2. com.ibm.team.workitem.linktype.scm.tracksChanges

Because I have found some change set links using trackschanges Id and after that when I try to fetchCompleteItem for the link it return null or exception like that data is not present in the database. I am using the below code to fetchCompleteItem.

Really stuck here please help:

```
for(Object wI : links){
  ILink link = (ILink) wI;
  Object source = link.getTargetRef().resolve();
  IChangeSetHandle changeSetHandle = (IChangeSetHandle) link.getTargetRef().resolve();
  wiHandles.add((IChangeSetHandle) link.getTargetRef().resolve());

  if (source instanceof IChangeSetHandle) {
    changeSet = (IChangeSet) repo.itemManager().fetchCompleteItem(
      changeSetHandle,
      IItemManager.DEFAULT, monitor);
    System.out.println("changeset---1"+changeSet);
  }
}
```

Comment: The first one seems to retrieve the associated WorkItem from a
ChangeSet (https://jazz.net/forum/questions/11911/how-can-i-determine-the-workitem-associated-with-changeset). The second one is about changeset links: https://jazz.net/forum/questions/209540/why-cant-i-find-any-changeset-links

Comment: @VonC I have some links with link type id - com.ibm.team.workitem.linktype.scm.tracksChanges.
I am confused if it is equivalent to change set or not?
Because when I try to resolve the tracks change link using change set code then it returns null .