# How to find out if work item change set file item is newly added or modified?

Tags: java, api, rtc

I have some change set objects and I need to find out if the file in the change set is newly added or modified. below is the code I am using to fetch the change set:

```
    IChangeSetHandle changeSets = convertToChangeSetHandles(extracted);

                        changeSet = (IChangeSet) repoApac.itemManager().fetchCompleteItem(changeSets,
                                    IItemManager.DEFAULT, monitor);

public static List<IFileItem> changeSetFileName(IChangeSet changeSet) throws TeamRepositoryException{
        IVersionableManager vm = SCMPlatform.getWorkspaceManager(repoApac).versionableManager(); 
        List changes = changeSet.changes(); 
        List<IFileItem> changeSetFileNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<changes.size();i++) { 
            Change change = (Change) changes.get(i); 
            IVersionableHandle after = change.afterState();
            if( after != null && after instanceof IFileItemHandle) { 
                IFileItem fileItem = (IFileItem) vm.fetchCompleteState(after, null); 
                changeSetFileNames.add(fileItem);
            } 
        } 
        return changeSetFileNames;
    }

        if(changeSet.isNewItem()){
                return "ADDED"; 
            }else{
                return "MODIFIED";
            }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: code - changeSet.isNewItem() everytime returns false, even if there are some new change sets

Comment: @VonC Any sugeestion?

Comment: Instead of ChangeSet, try getting a IWorkItem, as in https://jazz.net/forum/questions/237076/how-to-get-the-linked-workitem-ids-for-any-workitem-using-server-side-api. I haven't seen isNewItem apploed to changeSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working code:

```
for (IChange change : (List<IChange>) changeSet.changes()) {
                if (change.kind() == IChange.MODIFY) {
                    return "MODIFIED";
                }
                if (change.kind() == IChange.ADD) {
                    return "ADDED";
                }
            }
```

Comment: @VonC Can you help in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563104/how-to-develop-operation-advisor-plugins-in-rtc?noredirect=1#comment88136586_50563104