# How to develop operation advisor plugins in RTC?

Tags: java, api, plugins, rtc

[image: Here the list is blank[![and here I am not able to see the mentioned plugin]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UebRh.png)I have reference of this https://jazz.net/library/article/495 link and following the steps given in this article. But when I try to add dependencies, the window appears blank with no suggestions and this com.ibm.team.process.service jar file is not there in my RTC plain java client libraries. How would I find this jar file and continue on the plugin development. Please help

Comment: You are looking at an outdated article. You should refer to the newer version of the article, which is linked in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I went through that article too. But there I didn't find the satisfactory answer.

Comment: Can you add more details (OS, version of RTC, version of Java, screenshot of the dependency screen being blank, ...)

Comment: Yes, RTC version - 6.0.3 , OS - windows 7 enterprise, JDK 1.8.

Comment: Do you have any article link which I can follow and develop the plugin, I was following this article https://jazz.net/library/article/495 but looks like it is for older version of RTC.

Comment: Would instructions in https://jazz.net/forum/questions/22029/problems-with-rtc-20-development-environment-setup-guide regarding adding plugins or updating the MANIFEST.MF help?

Comment: The comments refer to https://jazz.net/library/article/1000